# É possível receber notificação por email de respostas?

Tags: suporte, notificações, duvida

Eu recebo de novas perguntas em algumas tags que sigo, mas não lembro onde selecionei, e não achei configuração de notificação por email aqui no site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Não, isto não é possível, a não ser se você ficar um bom tempo fora do site , pode receber notificação que tem coisas pendentes no site que você foi notificado e não estava presente, uma dessas notificações é uma nova resposta.

É possível receber notificações por RSS:

[image: Question feed]

Talvez possa usar alguma ferramenta que mande mensagens partindo do RSS.